# Bitcoin Exchange API - more frequent high low

Tags: bitcoin

Any way to get more a high-low value more frequent than every 24 hours from say the Bitstamp API ticker?
This link only tells you how to get the value for every 24 hours

https://www.bitstamp.net/api/

(this also seems to be a problem with every other exchange I've tried)

Comment: Not sure this is relevant for Stackoverflow, try bitcoin.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can get the current value in realtime via Firebase and coinbase: https://www.firebase.com/docs/data/real-time-bitcoin-exchange-rate.html

Answer (score 0):

24 hours is compared by time_now - 24 hours so it should give you updated rates every second or may be every minute depends on the configuration of the api file.